# how to delete something which is already written in output in c

Tags: c, graphics

so here is the thing I am trying to make something like 1d particle simulator which could simulate two particle but the problem is it takes time proccess and in that time I want to show the user something like loading... and then the loading vanishes and and answer is shown so I wanted to know if is it possible to delete something which already in the output part if so please tell how.
I am pretty knew to this platform so if I did any mistake please tell.

Comment: What kind of output? Text?

Comment: Something like ncurses with screen control? Or just use `\r` and print over the line again.

Comment: `printf("LOADING"); fflush(stdout); /*work, waste time*/ printf("\b\b\b\b\b\b\bANSWER: 42\n");`

Comment: "I am pretty knew to this platform" What platform? This is system specific, so it can't be answered unless we know the system.

Comment: output -loading...
platform -stackoverflow
system like what like do u mean compiler?
compiler- dev c++
os- windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code. Example Command-line progress bar:

```
// C program to create loading bar
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

// Function to creating loading bar
void loadingBar()
{
    // 0 - black background,
    // A - Green Foreground
    system("color 0A");

    // Initialize char for printing
    // loading bar
    char a = 177, b = 219;

    printf("\n\n\n\n");
    printf("\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t"
        + "Loading...\n\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t");

    // Print initial loading bar
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        printf("%c", a);

    // Set the cursor again starting
    // point of loading bar
    printf("\r");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t");

    // Print loading bar progress
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("%c", b);

        // Sleep for 1 second
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

// Driver Code
int main()
{
    // Function Call
    loadingBar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think there are 2 mistakes or maybe the fact i have different version of c or whatever it is 
1. my compiler is not int inside the for loop and is saying it only allowed in c99 or c11 whatever it was it could be fixed by t=declaring i int in start
2.    printf("\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t"
        + "Loading...\n\n");
this lines seems a mistake to me or maybe it is just version problem any ways it could be fixed by just removing merging both to make this
    printf("\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\tLoading...\n\n");
other then this its a perfect answer